# How to select rows with whole numbers from a column containing decimals

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I sampled my data inconsistently. Some of my data was collected at 5Hz and some of it was collected at 1Hz. I'd like to standardize it so I'd like to remove the data between each second interval. 
My dataframe column is in float format, because of the fractions of seconds, but I would only like to keep data from rows that are in whole seconds.

```
data = [["1",0, 1],["1",1, 4],['1',2,9],['1',3,4],["2",0, 4],['2',0.2, 2],['2',0.4, 2], ['2',0.6,1], ['2',0.8,5],['2',1.0, 1],['2',1.2, 6],['2',1.4, 6], ['2',1.6,1], ['2',1.8,5],['2',2.0, 1]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Day",'Second', 'Data'])
```

```
desired = [["1",0, 1],["1",1, 4], ['1',2,9],['1',3,4],["2",0, 4],['2',1.0, 1],['2',2.0, 1]] 
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(desired, columns = ["Day",'Second', 'Data'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Python Modulus](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html) operator as below to get your desired result

```
desired_df = df.loc[df.Second%1 == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   Day  Second  Data
0   1   0.0     1
1   1   1.0     4
2   1   2.0     9
3   1   3.0     4
4   2   0.0     4
5   2   1.0     1
6   2   2.0     1
```