# How to filter double type rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that has an "age" column in which only integer values ​​are possible.
However, for some wrong reason it comes with double values ​​in this column and I want to filter those rows out.
Anyone can help me how to filter rows based on double type in a dataframe using python?

> age 15 41.1 50
> output
> age 15 50

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows with whole numbers from a column containing decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149651/how-to-select-rows-with-whole-numbers-from-a-column-containing-decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
output = df[df["Age"].eq(df["Age"].astype(int,errors="ignore"))]
```